How to use data attribute values as the context for mark.js?
I'm trying to use Mark.js to find a search value in data attribute values. When a match is found, I'd like to highlight the attribute's element. In the HTML below, I want to highlight .terms, when a match is found in the data-definition value.
HTML
<div class="search-in-doc">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search this page" >
    <button data-search="prev"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></button>
    <button data-search="next"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
    <button data-search="clear"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button>
</div>
<div id="main">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a class="terms" data-definition="third-person singular present active subjunctive of consector." href="https://example.com">consectetur</a> adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod.</p>
    <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in <a class="terms" data-definition="actionable negligence or fault" href="https://anotherexample.com">culpa</a>.</p>
</div>

Javascript (in this code, I'm targeting #main as the context for testing. But I want to figure out how to target data-definition instead)

    var $input = $(".search-in-doc input[type='search']"),
    // clear button
    $clearBtn = $("button[data-search='clear']"),
    // prev button
    $prevBtn = $("button[data-search='prev']"),
    // next button
    $nextBtn = $("button[data-search='next']"),
    // the context where to search
    $content = $("#main"),
    // jQuery object to save <mark> elements
    $results,
    // the class that will be appended to the current
    // focused element
    currentClass = "current",
    // top offset for the jump (the search bar)
    offsetTop = 50,
    // the current index of the focused element
    currentIndex = 0;

  /**
   * Jumps to the element matching the currentIndex
   */
  function jumpTo() {
    if ($results.length) {
      var position,
        $current = $results.eq(currentIndex);
      $results.removeClass(currentClass);
      if ($current.length) {
        $current.addClass(currentClass);
        position = $current.offset().top - offsetTop;
        window.scrollTo(0, position);
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Searches for the entered keyword in the
   * specified context on input
   */
  $input.on("input", function() {
      localStorage.clear();
       searchVal = this.value;

   
    $content.unmark({
      done: function() {
        $content.mark(searchVal, {
          separateWordSearch: true,
          done: function() {
            $results = $content.find("mark");
            currentIndex = 0;
            jumpTo();
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });

  /**
   * Clears the search
   */
  $clearBtn.on("click", function() {
    localStorage.clear();
    console.log(localStorage); 
    $content.unmark();
    $input.val("").focus();
  });

  /**
   * Next and previous search jump to
   */
  $nextBtn.add($prevBtn).on("click", function() {
    if ($results.length) {
      currentIndex += $(this).is($prevBtn) ? -1 : 1;
      if (currentIndex < 0) {
        currentIndex = $results.length - 1;
      }
      if (currentIndex > $results.length - 1) {
        currentIndex = 0;
      }
      jumpTo();
    }
  });

I tried The JS below returns all elements with the data-definition attribute. But searches within this context match on the anchor element's text, not the attribute's value.
$content = document.querySelectorAll('[data-definition]');

If I can add my search value to the method below, then I get a NodeList of elements with a match in data-definition. Great. These results could be highlighted and the matches would be correct. But I'm not sure how to incorporate this into Mark.js. I don't know how or where to pass the search value as a variable to this context definition. And maybe there's another way that works better with Mark.js
$content = document.querySelectorAll('[data-definition*="' + searchVal + '"]'); 

